# WNS notify multiple clients

Tags: .net, wcf, push-notification, windows-runtime

I’m developing a WCF Service for Tile notifications for a winrt application.

Now I'm using a `foreach` to send the notification true WNS to the registered clients.
This `foreach` I can update by using a different thread to perform the requests.

The questing I have:

Isn’t there a way to create a batch and then send 1 request to WNS to notify all registered clients? Or is there a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you're using a foreach on your cloud/server app when you push your messgages to WNS?

I don't believe there is a batching mechanism.

The current model appears to be one call per channel, which means you'll want to watch out for any throttling mechanisms that happen inside of WNS.